# Bind a function to when mutiple keys are pressed in javascript using one function

Tags: javascript, onkeydown

was browsing a few key event javascript libarys and found [this one](https://craig.is/killing/mice) that I thought was pretty cool.Basically, using it you can do stuff sort of like this:

```
function bindFunctionToKeydownEvents(keys, callback) {
  // code here
}
```

where the keys could be just a key: `"k", "(", or "="`, 
a key combo: `"ctrl+k" or "shift+ctrl+k"`, 
or a sequence(typing a letter g then within 3 seconds, typing another letter o like gmail style)`g o` to do something
and then the callback would be a function.`function(){alert("hi");foo();bar();}`
Is there a way to just do this in one javascript function, since I don't want to add that library?
I really want it to be able to support multiple callbacks, for example, being able to run:
`bindFunctionToKeydownEvents("ctrl+k", function(){alert("hi")});`
and then do
`bindFunctionToKeydownEvents("ctrl+shift+k", function(){alert("hello")});`
and have it do both things when ctrl+shift+k is pressed.
i'm very new to javascript and keydown events so if you could explain the code that would be great. 
Even if only feel like showing me how to do a part of my requested syntax, that would be fine.

Comment: you can do whatever you want in js, basically. but why are you trying to avoid this library? If you don't want to use it, you have to recreate EVERYTHING it does yourself, which gets to be VERY hard in JS - especially if you want to support multiple browsers and versions of those browsers. in other words, you're trying to build/fly a rocket to mars, while you're still in diapers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with keypress since only in keypress you can change keyCode by a character:

```js
var keypress = {};
function bindFunctionToKeypressEvents(keys, callback) {
  keys = keys.toLowerCase();
  keypress[keys] = keypress[keys] || [];
  keypress[keys].push(callback);
}
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var str = '';
  if (e.shiftKey) {
    str += 'shift+';
  }
  if (e.ctrlKey) {
    str += 'ctrl+';
  }
  str += String.fromCharCode(e.charCode).toLowerCase();
  if (keypress[str] && keypress[str].length) {
    keypress[str].forEach(function(fn) {
      fn();
    });
  }
}, true);

bindFunctionToKeypressEvents('shift+l', function() {
  alert('shift+l');
});
```

it will only work when shift is the first one.